# How to retrieve the url of a web page loaded in an iframe after disabling browser security?

Tags: javascript, iframe, solid-js

I have embedded an iframe in my solid-js application on my localhost. The page my iframe contains has links to other pages cross-domain. I would like to be able to get the url of the current page loaded in my iframe. For this, I have therefore disabled web security on my Chrome browser. Here is the code I use to retrieve the url of the loaded webpage in my iframe:

```
document.getElementById("iframeID")?.contentWindow.document.href
```

However, when I try to get the url of the webpage, I get nothing at all and it doesn't give me any error.

I also tried this code but nothing:

```
document.getElementById("iframeID")?.contentWindow.document.url
```

Apparently my code is wrong, so I wonder if someone could help me. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
document.getElementById("iframeID")?.src
```

Comment: I am looking to obtain the url of the current page contained in the iframe and not the url of the page loaded by the iframe at the base. Your solution does not help me. Thank you all the same and have a good evening!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not targeting the right element. Alternatively you can use a ref instead of querying the element imperatively:

```js
import { render } from "solid-js/web";

function App() {
  let ref: HTMLIFrameElement | undefined;

  const getUrl = () => {
    if (ref) {
      console.log(ref.contentWindow?.location.href);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <iframe
        width="100%"
        height="300"
        id="myiframe"
        src="https://solidjs.com"
        ref={ref}
      ></iframe>
      <button type="button" onClick={getUrl}>
        Get Url
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

render(() => <App />, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

Make sure you get the right permissions for the embedded page otherwise you will get `SecurityError`.